# Does wso2 exposes any API to check whether user account is locked

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating users using RemoteUserStoreManagerService .When i try to add user with same ID whose account is locked i receive a remote exception that

"username exists already .Pick a new username."

Is there an API with which i can check whether the user account is locked so that i can resend a recovery mail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RemoteUserStoreManagerService for this. Use getUserClaimValues API as follows.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getUserClaimValues>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>hasinitg</ser:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:profileName>default</ser:profileName>
      </ser:getUserClaimValues>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It will return claims as follows. Then you can get AccountLocked Claim

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getUserClaimValuesResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:ax2668="http://dao.service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2662="http://core.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2663="http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2666="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2670="http://tenant.core.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>sub</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>phone_number</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>0772254810</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/mobile</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>0772254810</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.lastModified</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>2016-04-28T08:32:31</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>preferred_username</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>given_name</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>false</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastLoginTime</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>1461812009558</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/fullname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://axschema.org/contact/country/home</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Sri Lanka</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastPasswordUpdateTime</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>1461811974908</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/streetaddress</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>32/35A,Ganegoda</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/country</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Sri Lanka</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>name</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:emails.home</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>isuradilhara@gmail.com</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:id</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>e612fe60-8680-4fb7-a4bd-373baed85106</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>family_name</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>gunasinghe</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/role</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Internal/everyone</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:addresses.streetAddress</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>32/35A,Ganegoda</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:name.familyName</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>gunasinghe</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>fullname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://axschema.org/namePerson/last</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>gunasinghe</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/mobile</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>0772254810</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/username</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:emails</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasini_home.com</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/lastname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>gunasinghe</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/telephone</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>0772254810</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:phoneNumbers.mobile</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>0772254810</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:userName</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>country</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Sri Lanka</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/givenname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:emails.work</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasini_work.com</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>hasinitg</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>email</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>isuradilhara@gmail.com</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>false</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/streetaddress</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>32/35A,Ganegoda</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/country</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Sri Lanka</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.created</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>

            <ax2668:claimUri>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>gunasinghe</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:addresses.country</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>Sri Lanka</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2668:ClaimDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2668:claimUri>urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.location</ax2668:claimUri>
            <ax2668:description xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:dialectURI xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:displayOrder>0</ax2668:displayOrder>
            <ax2668:displayTag xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:regEx xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2668:required>false</ax2668:required>
            <ax2668:supportedByDefault>false</ax2668:supportedByDefault>
            <ax2668:value>https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/e612fe60-8680-4fb7-a4bd-373baed85106</ax2668:value>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getUserClaimValuesResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks .It works. Also i was able to get the account lock claim alone using getUserClaimValueForClaims.

Comment: When i use registerUser from userinformationrecoveryservice with Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=true it locks the user when created.
But when i add user using RemoteUserStoreManagerService it does not lock the user.Is it the expected behaviour ?

Comment: If you have enabled Identity Management Event listner, user should be locked in both cases

Answer (score 2):

In Identity Server 5.1.0, you can use `getAllUserIdentityClaims` method of `UserIdentityManagementAdminService` . It will return all the identity claims of user and from there you can check the value of accountLocked claim.

Comment: I tried what you said,but it returns me only the Admin claims.Where should i pass the username in the request.

Comment: Also i cannot find the accountlocked attribute in datastore.Though i can see that the account is locked in the Admin console.Is there any config that i need to change